# Regex where a number can start with 9 but not 999 consecutively

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to make a regex where:

1. a number can start from 3,5,6 or 9
2. the number cannot be starting with 999.

Thus for example, `93214211` is matched, but `99912345` should not be matched.

This is what I have for now which satisfies the first requirement:

`^3|^5|^6|^9|[^...]}`

I'm stuck at the 2nd requirement for a while now.
Thanks!

Comment: What about 99321421?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `negative lookahead` like

```
^(?!999)[3569]\d{7}$ <-- assuming the number to be of 8 digits
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tC6cW2/1)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
^ #Start of string
  (?!999) #Negative lookahead. Asserts that its impossible to match 999 in beginning
  [3569] #Match any of 3, 5, 6 or 9
  \d{7} #Match 7 digits
$ #End of string
```

Comment: Thank you for such quick response!! The previous one before you editted sufficed, as I had added a condition to validate maxLength to 8 in my cakephp program.

Comment: @AlfonsoKhiew now you can do it without a condition for checking 8 digits with given regex..

Comment: Just for fun, a similar regex with a lookbehind: [`^[3569]\d{2}(?<!9{3})\d{5}$`](https://regex101.com/r/qP4uF3/1).